# Is it possible to do update by query with bulk api in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to do a bulk update by query, can this be done? I've managed to get create working but can't seem to get this one right.

Comment: Please publish the query

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? Do you have any reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

No and it doesn't make sense as update by query is already a bulk operation behind the scene.

Comment: I am guessing it can be done. Querying first and then doing single updates based on the doc id , but it sounds pointless and unnecessary having the the update API for that.